# EC2 Haproxy stops taking requests

Tags: amazon-ec2, load-balancing, haproxy

I am using haproxy with Apache to keep alive an EC2 server. Sometimes haproxy stops taking new requests. If I reload haproxy it starts working normally. I have disabled iptables and increased open file limit but no luck. Below is my configuration.
Please guide me to what I did wrong.

```
    global
    log 127.0.0.1   local5
    maxconn   190001 
    daemon
    nbproc      2 
    stats bind-process 1
    stats socket /tmp/haproxy level admin
    debug

    defaults
    log global
    timeout server 86400000
    timeout connect 86400000
    timeout client 86400000
    #timeout queue   30s
    #timeout tarpit 60s
    #timeout client  30s
    #timeout connect 30s
    #timeout server  30s
    #option abortonclose
    #option httpclose
    mode    http
    option  httplog
    #option  dontlognull
    option forwardfor
    #option http-server-close
    #timeout http-keep-alive 30s

    stats enable
    stats hide-version
    stats show-desc Master Server
    stats auth admin:password
    #stats auth admin:admin
    stats uri /haproxyStats
    stats refresh  15s

    #errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/maintenance.html

    frontend HTTP
    bind 0.0.0.0:80

    acl network_allowed src 1.1.1.1

    acl restricted_page path_beg /blog/wp-admin
    block if restricted_page !network_allowed

    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ http

    acl is_blog url_beg  /blog
    use_backend Blog if is_blog

    default_backend Apache-Cluster
    bind-process    2

    frontend HTTPS
    bind 0.0.0.0:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/crt.com.pem
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
    bind-process    2
    default_backend Apache-Cluster
    acl is_blog url_beg  /blog
    use_backend Blog if is_blog

    backend Apache-Cluster
    redirect prefix http://www.example.com code 301 if { hdr(host) -i example.com }
    #redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
    redirect scheme https  if !{ ssl_fc }  { path_beg -i /order/checkout }

    balance source
    option httplog
    option abortonclose
    option httpclose
    option forwardfor
    cookie LOADBAL  insert
    option httpchk GET /working.php
    server APPA 10.0.0.11:80 cookie APPA weight 50 maxconn 40000  check inter 4000 rise 2 fall 2  
    server APPB 10.0.0.12:80 cookie APPB weight 50 maxconn 40000  check inter 4000 rise 2 fall 2

    backend Blog
    mode http
    option httplog
    option abortonclose
    option httpclose
    option forwardfor
    cookie LOADBAL  insert
    server BLOG 10.0.0.12:80 cookie BLOG weight 50 maxconn 512
```

Comment: Why did you change default timeouts? Have you checked how many open sessions there are when no requests comes thru haproxy? Tcpdump done? Wheres netstat?

Comment: What does "stops taking requests" mean? Timeout? Connection refused?  What's in the syslog?  Do stats keep working? Why `nbproc 2`?  What version of haproxy?

Comment: stop taking request mean i can't open my website till i reload/restart. netstat show lot of TIME_WAIT, change default timeout because of some time our order page gets timeout, nbproc 2 we have 2 core processor. how can i check open sessions?